# Printing only specific part of a link using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse a website using the following code. I am able to parse the website and print data, however, I only want to print only a part of the data in the link. Can anyone provide inputs on how can this be done?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import argparse
import urllib
import urllib2
import getpass
import re
import requests

def update (url):
    print url
    req = urllib2.Request(url=url)
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        txt = f.read()
        soup = bs(txt)
        print soup
        f.close()


def main ():
    #For logging
    print "test"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is the update.py script created by test')
    parser.add_argument('-u','--url',action='store',dest='url',default=None,help='<Required> url link',required=True)
    results = parser.parse_args()# collect cmd line args
    url = results.url
    #print url
    update(url)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Following is the current output. Expected result is shown below.

```
current output :-

==== Test results ====

results are in \\data\loc

==== <font color="#008000">Build Combo</font> ====

{| border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
|-
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test1
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test2
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test3
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test4
|-
| [http:link.com]
|}

==== <font color="#008000">COde:</font> ====

Expected output:-

==== <font color="#008000">Build Combo</font> ====

{| border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
|-
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test1
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test2
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test3
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test4
|-
| [http:link.com]
|}
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be the first to admit I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but I think it's that you want to print only the `a` element rather than the whole `soup` if I'm not mistaken. If that's the case, you need to `find` the element you want to print and then, well, print it. Your update method might look more like this, assuming you're hunting for an `a` element.

```
def update (url):
    print url
    req = urllib2.Request(url=url)
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        txt = f.read()

        soup = bs(txt)
        a_element = soup.find("a")
        print a_element

    f.close()
```